# What is this import_umath function?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

When compiling a bunch of Cython-generated C files that interface with Numpy, I get the warning:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:226:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
```

I can't seem to get rid of that. Figuring this might be similar to `np.import_array()`, which gets rid of a related warning (and is actually [required](http://wiki.cython.org/tutorials/numpy#C-APIinitalization) for using the Numpy C API), I tried `np.import_umath()` at top level, but the warning persists. How do I get rid of it?

(Cython 0.17.4, Numpy 1.6.2.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same warning. No idea how to fix it though.

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [thread on the Cython mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail//cython-devel/2012-March/002137.html) that discusses this a little bit. I believe that the discussion was concerning the Cython test suite, but I think the same ideas can be applied to generated files.

In essence, the issue involved a hack that was done in order to avoid C compiler warnings about unused functions.

The [code file in question](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/run/numpy_common.pxi) currently looks like this:

```
cdef extern from *:
   bint FALSE "0"
   void import_array()
#   void import_umath()

if FALSE:
    import_array()
#    import_umath()
```

In the past, the `import_umath()` portions were uncommented, but as it turns out, this was causing errors when building in C++ mode. So it appears that [it was decided](http://mail.python.org/pipermail//cython-devel/2012-March/002156.html) that a compiler warning is much better than a broken build.

In short, it seems this particular warning exists for the sake of C++ compatibility, and can be safely ignored. I suppose if you *really* dislike it, and if you're building in C mode, then you could try to do the same hack, by importing a similar `.pxi` file with a call to `import_umath()` inside of your Cython code.

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what it says, is that there's a function in the code, that's declared but not used, so perhaps its obsolete and shouldnt be there. Since its just a warning, and not very dangerous one (unless you'll leave a lot of such functions, clobbering the code, increasing ram usage, binary size and so on) I would simply ignore it - most probably its not worth your time ;)

Comment: I am ignoring it. However, I was also ignoring `_import_array` previously, which was a mistake.