# way to eliminate Cython numpy compilation warnings?

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I ran into the problem described here ([What is this import_umath function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201192/what-is-this-import-umath-function)) and wanted to know if there is a fix for it? I have the exact same case where compiling Cython code that uses numpy with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()
```

generates many warnings about `_import_umath` not being used:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:226:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
```

removing `np.import_array()` does not change the result. Like one of the posters suggested in the above thread, I tried adding this in my `.pxd/.pyx` file:

```
cdef extern from *:
    import_umath()
```

this also made no difference. How can this warnings be eliminated?

Comment: Have you tried disabling that specific warning class in the compile command line?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: How do I pass arguments to C compiler from `setup.py` with cython?

Comment: @user248237dfsf did you try the approach below?

Answer (score 6):

You can pass arguments to the C compiler using the keyword `extra_compile_args` in your `setup.py`. For example, this will not generate warnings:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import numpy

extensions=[
    Extension("abc",
             ["abc.pyx"],
             include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
             extra_compile_args=["-w"]
            )
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Cython Tricks and Tips](http://docs.cython.org/0.17.4/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) they explain that you need:

```
cdef extern from *:
    pass
```

when you import extern packages. [I already needed this trick to write a wrapper](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature/tree/master/cubature), maybe it will work for you too...